# Add and remove class iteration in multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add and remove `active` class on multiple divs in a time interval using `setTimeout()`, `addClass()`, `removeClass()`...

```
function classAddRemove() {
  $("div").each(function(index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("div").eq(index - 1).removeClass("active");
      $("div").eq(index).addClass("active");
    }, 500 * (index + 1));
  });
}
```

Code run once...and add remove `active` class in a `500ms` interval...

Now I want that my function execute again and again...for that I tried to call my function inside itself.

```
function classAddRemove() {
  $("div").each(function(index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("div").eq(index - 1).removeClass("active");
      $("div").eq(index).addClass("active");
    }, 500 * (index + 1));
  });
  classAddRemove();
}
```

But somehow the add and remove `active` class not executing again...I want to know where I am going wrong...I doubt is my code creating a infinite loop...?

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function classAddRemove() {
    $("div").each(function(index) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("div").eq(index - 1).removeClass("active");
        $("div").eq(index).addClass("active");
      }, 500 * (index + 1));
    });
  }
  classAddRemove();
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

div.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

Comment: Instead of setTimeout(), try using setInterval(), setInterval() will continue to fire off at the desired interval

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to loop through the elements repeatedly it would make more sense to use `setInterval()`, then to go back to the `first()` element once the last one is reached. Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function classAddRemove() {
    var $divs = $('div');
    setInterval(function() {
      var $next = $divs.filter('.active').next();
      $divs.removeClass('active');
      
      if (!$next.length)
        $next = $divs.first();
        
      $next.addClass('active');
    }, 500);
  }

  classAddRemove();
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

div.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

Comment: how can i add class on button click ?